# Should you always add list.copy() / dict.copy() when passing a list/dict to a function？

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I had a painful experience today that I accidentally passed a list to a function, and took me ages to debug. The function was meant to take in a list and create a copy of similar list. I did not realize this modified my original list.

```
L = [0,0,0,0,0]

def similar_list(a_list):
    a_list [0] = a_list[0]+1
    return a_list

L_similar = similar_list(L)
print(L)
print(L_similar)

#result shows
#[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
#[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I think the best way is in the first line of the similar_list function, add a_list = a_list.copy().  Is there a better way to this? I am asking as in my limited study of python, I don't recall seeing this often in sample code. Would appreciate it if you could let me know if this is a standard practice. (Still, this seems a thing that is very easy to get wrong, and very hard to notice when it is wrong..)

Comment: Well, NO: You should instead adjust your way of thinking about python lists and only make a copy, if you really need one. The pain you felt will help you to remember next time:). By the way, you will feel that pain once again before you discover deepcopy :).

Comment: No, no you shouldn't. In general, it is pretty clear what modifies a list. Generally, functions should not mutate their inputs, if they do, it should be clearly documented

Comment: I think I've actually never ever used `.copy` in all my years using python.

Comment: @Stef then how do you avoid modifying the list inside functions?

Comment: `a[:]` is the way I do it.

Comment: @Learning_man I either write functions that don't need to modify the list at all, and don't need to modify a copy either; or functions that need a profoundly-modified copy, in which case the "copy" is made with another tool, such as `sorted`, `map`, or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what `similar_list()` is supposed to do.

If you intend to modify the original list, just change it in place as you've seen:

```
def similar_list(a_list):
    a_list[0] += 1
```

As you notice, I don't return the original list. Per [Python's convention](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list), functions or methods that modify the input object, do not return it as to avoid confusion and be clearer.

If you intend to return a new list, which has numerous advantages related to immutability, you can copy and then modify:

```
def similar_list(a_list):
    newlist = a_list.copy()
    newlist[0] += 1
    return newlist
```

It is a standard practice if you have the need to copy, but eventually it is yours to decide.

For some pros and cons you can consult with Python's official guide on [functional programming](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html).

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the convention. Indeed it would help me a little bit..  Can you specify slightly more on how is this related to functional programming? I have had some tutorials with lambda functions and higher-order functions, but cannot immediately see how it is related to my question.

Comment: @Learning_man I don't really see any relevant infomration in that HOWTO, but in purely functional programming languages (which python is absolutely not) *everything is immutable*. Indeed, you cannot even re-assign variables. So their are entire paradigms of programming where objects are all immutable

Comment: @Learning_man maybe [this](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html) will be a bit more relevant. Take it with a grain of salt as he's very opinionated but what he says is mostly true.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `L_similar = similar_list(L)` you can use `L_similar = similar_list(L[:])` to avoid any change in your original list.

Try this:

```
L = [0,0,0,0,0]

def similar_list(a_list):
    a_list [0] = a_list[0]+1
    return a_list

L_similar = similar_list(L[:])
print(L)
print(L_similar)

#result shows
#[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
#[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**[EDIT]:**

However, both methods `L[:]` and `L.copy()` will return the shallow copy of the list. It means if you modify any of the nested list elements, changes are reflected in both the list. Consider the below example:

```
L = [1, [2, 3], 4]
L_copy = L.copy()

L[1][0] = 5

print(L)
print(L_copy)

#result shows
#[1, [5, 3], 4]
#[1, [5, 3], 4]
```

To avoid this problem, you should use the `copy.deepcopy()` from the `copy` module.

```
import copy

L = [1, [2, 3], 4]
L_copy = copy.deepcopy(L)

L[1][0] = 5

print(L)
print(L_copy)

#result shows
#[1, [5, 3], 4]
#[1, [2, 3], 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. indeed this worked too, but I suppose when the object is more complicated than a single flat list it might still be necessary to use copy()

Comment: Hi @Learning_man, please check my edit for further clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. I encountered this deepcopy concept before but never understood it. Now I do. I think the best way to learn something is to get screwed by it...